# What is the importance of rule ids in Ensighten

Tags: javascript, web-analytics, tms

In Ensighten, I could see rule ids in each generated tag code. What is the importance of rule ids?

Answer (score 1):

Rule ids are essentially a non-sequential version number of a tag that we publicly expose. For most day-to-day users the deployment id is all you need when talking about a tag but when we have to investigate things on the back end it helps is identify an exact point in the tag's history.